# The color of the box shadow I am using is not showing in Microsoft Edge or IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a pattern that is mostly white and grey, and I am using the box shadow property to apply a blue color filter to give it color through CSS. This effect works on firefox and chrome, but I am unable to see it reflected on IE11, Edge, and Facebook browser.

Here is my code:

```css
.content-space-two {
    position:relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: inherit;
    background: url('../../assets/patternBackground.jpg') no-repeat center 
    center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    min-height: 800px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2000px #1b557ef5;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2000px #1b557ef5;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2000px #1b557ef5;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2000px #1b557ef5;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px 2000px #1b557ef5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#1b557ef5** is not a valid hex color. The valid hex color is made of 6 characters/ digits (or 3 in some cases).